# How to implement long polling by writing to a file in Python using Flask-RESTful with multiple clients?

Tags: python, flask, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, flask-restful

I am in the process of developing a webApp in Python using Flask framework.

In implementing a particular task, I had to use the concept of long polling. After some searching, I found this [link](https://github.com/sigilioso/long_polling_example) (Simple long-polling example) to be useful in my case.
It is a simple web polling example based on Flask and Flask-restful on server side and jQuery on client side. The code in this example polls to check if an update/change is made to the .txt (`data.txt`) file, if so, it is displayed on the web page.

I wrote a small piece of code (as shown below) that updates data.txt file and observed that the contents was indeed shown on the web page ***as the file was being modified***.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

def delete_content(fName):
    with open(fName, "w"):
        pass

def write_to_file(status):
    with open("/Flask_app/data.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(status + '\n')
        print(status)

delete_content('/Flask_app/data.txt')
for i in range(5):
    write_to_file('printing ' + str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

**The issue** - if there are multiple clients running the above code, depending on the time the clients starts, the output on the web page appears to be mixed i.e. contents written to the file by multiple 
 clients are shown.

For example, if there are two clients modifying the file, the output on the web page is something like -

`1 2 3 1 2 4 3 4` ... instead of

`1 2 3 4` for `Client 1` and

`1 2 3 4` for `Client 2` separately.

How do i modify the code such that each client will see only its own contents (that it has written to the data file) on the web page?

Sorry for having an external link to describe the issue. I intentionally did that to keep the post short. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you found is just a simple example that was written for learning, it just shows how content can be updated in client-side when it was changed in server side, please note it is just that.

Now you have multiple *things* changing the data, and it is shown in clients as it is changed (the piece of code you showed would be running in the server-side not the client-side).

If you want clients to modify the content, it is a different problem. You would need to perform a different request. By the other hand, if each client should have its own copy of the data, then you would also need to keep that in mind in order to identify it and make a copy for each one.